# Request XML can't show after post

Tags: php, xml, api, codeigniter, curl

I'm trying to post $noKartu, $tglSep, $noMR, $tglRujukan, $noRujukan, $ppkRujukan, $diagAwal, $tujuan to CURL with XML format but in $scml (request xml format) variable $noKartu etc above was not found. Could someone help me, please?

Here is my Controller:

```
public function cetak_sep() {
        {
            //post input data dari form
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
            $tglSep = date('Y-m-d');
            $noKartu = $this->input->post('noKartu');
            $tglRujukan = $this->input->post('tglRujukan');
            $noRujukan = $this->input->post('noRujukan');
            $ppkRujukan = $this->input->post('ppkRujukan');
            $diagAwal = $this->input->post('diagAwal');
            $tujuan = $this->input->post('tujuan');
            $kodeDPJP = $this->input->post('kodeDPJP');
            $noMR = $this->input->post('noMR');
            $noTelp = $this->input->post('noTelp');

            $scml = '
            {
               "request": {
                  "t_sep": {
                     "noKartu": "'.$noKartu.'",
                     "tglSep": "'.$tglSep.'",
                     "ppkPelayanan": "0112R060",
                     "jnsPelayanan": "2",
                     "klsRawat": "3",
                     "noMR": "'.$noMR.'",
                     "rujukan": {
                        "asalRujukan": "1",
                        "tglRujukan": "'.$tglRujukan.'",
                        "noRujukan": "'.$noRujukan.'",
                        "ppkRujukan": "'.$ppkRujukan.'"
                     },
                     "catatan": "-",
                     "diagAwal": "'.$diagAwal.'",
                     "poli": {
                        "tujuan": "'.$tujuan.'",
                        "eksekutif": "0"
                     },
                     "cob": {
                        "cob": "0"
                     },
                     "katarak": {
                        "katarak": "0"
                     },
                     "jaminan": {
                        "lakaLantas": "0",
                        "penjamin": {
                            "penjamin": "null",
                            "tglKejadian": "null",
                            "keterangan": "null",
                            "suplesi": {
                                "suplesi": "0",
                                "noSepSuplesi": "null",
                                "lokasiLaka": {
                                    "kdPropinsi": "null",
                                    "kdKabupaten": "null",
                                    "kdKecamatan": "null"
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                     },
                     "skdp": {
                        "noSurat": "-",
                        "kodeDPJP": "'.$kodeDPJP.'"
                     },
                     "noTelp": "'.$noTelp.'",
                     "user": "admin.tebet"
                  }
               }
            } 
            ';

            //cons.id dan secretKey dari BPJS
            $cons_id = "19597"; //Ganti dengan consumerID dari BPJS
            $secretKey = "1sU3D5470D"; //Ganti dengan consumerSecret dari BPJS

            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
            $tStamp = strval(time()-strtotime('1970-01-01 00:00:00'));
            $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $cons_id."&".$tStamp, $secretKey, true);
            $encodedSignature = base64_encode($signature);

            $arrheader = array(
                'X-cons-id: '.$cons_id,
                'X-timestamp: '.$tStamp,
                'X-signature: '.$encodedSignature,
                'Content-type: Application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            );

            $url = 'https://dvlp.bpjs-kesehatan.go.id/VClaim-Rest/SEP/1.1/insert';  //Lihat katalog

            $process = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrheader);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $scml);

            $return = curl_exec($process);
            curl_close($process);

            $response = json_decode($return, true);

            if ($response['metaData']['message']!="Sukses"){
                echo $response['metaData']['message'];
            } else {
                echo $response['response']['sep']['noSep'];
            }
        }
```

I think that format XML request is no problem, after post, there are ($noKartu, etc) no value

Comment: error is clear, you are passing blank value to `foto`, so either set value for `foto` field or allow it `null` from phpmyadmin

Comment: can you make var_dump($filename) to see what's its value ?

Comment: Could you explain , how make the var_dump ? @AngelDeykov

Comment: just write - var_dump($filename);die; - right after the line where you declare $filename and see it will show you its value

Comment: In your controller ... before - if ($filename != "") ...

Comment: As @ Devsi Odedra mentioned you're passing empty value for "foto", also 1st you're checking if $filename is empty, and doing absolutely the same thing if $filename is empty or not... It doesn't make any sense! If $filename is empty you should throw some exeption, since obviously it is required to have some value

Comment: the value $filename is "NULL" @Angel Deykov , please advice , thanks

Comment: $upload['detail'] should get its value from uploadfile() IF ($this->upload->do_upload($var)) else it returns 0, so I suppose uploadfile function is returning you 0 in general. Make var_dump($upload) in your controller and if value is 0 that's the case ...

Comment: i've try, and the result is `array(1) { ["detail"]=> int(0) }` , what must i do

Comment: well problem is defined - function uploadfile returns you 0, so - if ($this->upload->do_upload($var)) - check is failing, you should find out why .... you have all the code, just follow all the steps that code is taking and you'll get to the root of the problem